# Reporting models: Add intercept from fixed effect including confidence intervals

Tags: mixed-model, confidence-interval, generalized-linear-model, fixed-effects-model

Suppose I have a fixed effect model where I investigate a time series of measurements. My estimate + CI gives me the changes from intercept and a p-value. 
So stage 1 is baseline and the output gives me the change from baseline for each timepoint. The output is not the change since last time point, but the change from baseline for each time point.

It would be nice to report the estimate +CI as the absolute number instead of the change because it would be easier for the reader. 
Am I allowed to add my intercept est. to estimate for stage 2 and do the same for the low and high CI.
So for stage 2 I would add 73.69 to 2.01 to get my estimate and and add 69.14 to 1.01 to get lower CI and add 3.01 to 78.248 to get my higher CI.
So for stage 2 I would report that the estimate was: 75.7 [95%CI 70.2-81.3]
I would then do the same for the other stages. 
Output from model:
[image]

Comment: No!, you can add the estimates but you cannot add the intervals, you will need to build additional contrasts for that. Also something smells fishy here, time series data and fixed effects model?

Comment: I figured that - I guess I could relevel the model to set a new baseline to get the CI. And regarding fixed effects: I meant the fixed effects from a mixed model.

Comment: Do you perchance use R?

Comment: yes I use R studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how to solve your problem in R. I will use some toy data with 3 factors.

```
> mod=lm(mpg~factor(gear),data=mtcars)
> summary(mod)

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ factor(gear), data = mtcars)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-6.7333 -3.2333 -0.9067  2.8483  9.3667 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)     16.107      1.216  13.250 7.87e-14 ***
factor(gear)4    8.427      1.823   4.621 7.26e-05 ***
factor(gear)5    5.273      2.431   2.169   0.0384 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 4.708 on 29 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.4292,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.3898 
F-statistic:  10.9 on 2 and 29 DF,  p-value: 0.0002948
```

Now we use new contrasts

```
> library(multcomp)
> k=rbind(gear3=c(1,0,0),
>         gear4=c(1,1,0),
>         gear5=c(1,0,1))
> summary(glht(mod,linfct=k))

     Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Fit: lm(formula = mpg ~ factor(gear), data = mtcars)

Linear Hypotheses:
           Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
gear3 == 0   16.107      1.216   13.25   <1e-10 ***
gear4 == 0   24.533      1.359   18.05   <1e-10 ***
gear5 == 0   21.380      2.106   10.15   <1e-10 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
(Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)
```

And from this also come CI

```
> confint(glht(mod,linfct=k))

     Simultaneous Confidence Intervals

Fit: lm(formula = mpg ~ factor(gear), data = mtcars)

Quantile = 2.5272
95% family-wise confidence level


Linear Hypotheses:
           Estimate lwr     upr    
gear3 == 0 16.1067  13.0346 19.1787
gear4 == 0 24.5333  21.0987 27.9680
gear5 == 0 21.3800  16.0591 26.7009
```

Comment: That is great solution, thanks - the only thing that requires effort is to create the k matrix of 0 and 1 if you have many levels. To make sure you get the right combo.

Comment: @UserLG Yes, that can be a pain, however in some cases you can use some canned functions that allow you to bypass this. Have a look at the mcp() function which can be used in the linfct argument.